# How to remove only some spaces from string?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have an output like this:

```
"Please choose Video #1. Audio #2."
```

But my desired output should look like:

```
"Please choose Video#1. Audio#2."
```

I tried with Replace method but it replaces all the white spaces between whether I need to replace only one white space. Please suggest me how I can achieve this output. I would like to mention that I am using C# here. Thanks.

Comment: How about replacing " #" with "#"?

Comment: Your example actually removes two spaces, not one space

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a simple [`string.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx):

```
string newString = yourString.Replace(" #", "#");
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer in such situations using regular expression as they can provide more *structured* way of describing what you want change into what:

```
string input = "Please choose Video #1. Audio #2.";
string pattern = @"(\w+) (#\d+)";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1$2");
```

Comment: I was trying to make one myself. This is also working: ` (#\d+)`.

Comment: Then it's easier to use positive lookahead, ex.: `string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+(?=#\d+)", string.Empty);`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Konrad Kokosa for the solution.